# How to remove 30 second interval restriction when sending mail?

Tags: messages

I noticed that when I try send an email to another person, in quick sucession, I get a an error message that says that I should wait for 30 seconds before I can send next email.

How do I remove this restriction?

I have seen in the documentation that there are some [settings to edit re-submission time interval, but only for comments.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html)

This is the contents of the body when I tried to submit

```
<div id="content">
<h1>The form you submitted contained the following errors</h1>
<ul><li>You are only allowed to send a Private Message every 30 seconds</li>
</ul>
<p><a href='JavaScript:history.go(-1)'>Return to Previous Page</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try by making change into the file "system/expressionengine/modules/email/mod.email.php". In this module file, around line number 28, you can see the variable `$email_time_interval`. Set its value as 1.

**======================EDITED===================**

I found it. There is a hidden config variable `prv_msg_throttling_period` for it. so you need to set this config variable within config file system/expressionengine/config/config.php like:
`$config['prv_msg_throttling_period'] = '1';`

See here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#prv-msg-throttling-period

I hope, it would work for you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to match. The value is 20 seconds, while the error I got is 30 seconds. I also tried testing it and it didn't work.

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: I got another problem. It says "You are not authorized to perform this action". But I guess that for another question.